# Android Studio changing background color from fragment not working?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I am trying to change the background color of my whole application through a settings page, I have searched for a long time and so far cannot find a solution.

So, inside the fragment I have a button, and it acts as a toggle. When clicking the background color changes as it should, from white to grey interchangeably.

Here is the logic for the button:

```
Button changeBGButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_change_bg);
    changeBGButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (((MainActivity)getActivity()).bgWhite == true)
            {
                //White is true, set to grey
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).bgWhite = false;
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).bgGrey = true;
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Set is white to false, grey to true.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (((MainActivity)getActivity()).bgWhite == false && ((MainActivity)getActivity()).bgGrey == true)
            {
                //White is true, set to grey
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).bgWhite = true;
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).bgGrey = false;
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Set is white to true, grey to false.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

The main activity, inside **OnCreateView** override method is responsible for changing the background color, and it does. Upon clicking the button it changes.

But...
When pressing the back button to return to the previous screen in the backstack the background becomes white, if I then go to the settings page again it is grey, and again changes to white on pressing back.

It is acting as if only the fragment has the background changed, but the layout **contentLayout** only exists on the mainLayout not the fragment.

I suspect during the calling of the **Fragment Lifecycle Methods** the background is being reset, But I do not know how to make it persist as no instance is saved on the back button pressed.

Anyway. Here is the logic that changes the background, including the overriding method:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    if (contentMain != null) //Only do this if we have a hope at not crashing the application/
    if (bgWhite == true && bgGrey == false)
    {
        contentMain.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    }
    else if (bgGrey == true && bgWhite == false)
    {
        contentMain.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#888888"));
    }

    return super.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
}
```

I have tried to do it inside of the **OnBackstackChangeListener** too but the same result is experienced. Please help me out.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a bit ambiguous, but by what i think the problem is mainly because the color you are setting is from the `onCreateView()` method of your fragment, if the `contentMain` layout in resident on the activity which holds the fragments then you can create a method on that activity that change the color from the activity rather than the `onCreateView` of the fragment.

Thus you button click will look like this::

```
(MainActivity)getActivity().changeBgColor(bgGrey);
```

so the changes that you make here are done through the activity which controls all the fragments rather than the fragment itself.

Hope that help, good luck.

Comment: Yes, but it appears the changes are reset on returning to main activity. Would this not result in the same thing.

I think the activity is being re-created maybe, but know no way to check.

Comment: Nope the activity created again, but the state of the activity before the fragment was called is set as the current state, that makes u feel it's recreated, keep the color of the frame layout container of the fragment transparent and set the color through the activity by make a public method in the activity and calling it on the click of the button, so when you exit the fragment the activity will hav the new bg color since u made the changes through the activity. Try it once!